# installed samba, now ssh clients cannot connect

Tags: ssh, samba

I want to install Samba on my Linux Mint 14 Nadia server, but when I do, my clients that use SSH can no longer connect.  All attempts fail immediately with a

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

What do I need to change to have `smb` up and running and still have `ssh` clients able to connect?

**Edit**

As krowe points out, samba was already installed, I had just never activated it.  The point I think he missed is that *before* I activited smbd my ssh connections were working fine, and have been for over a year.  Once samba was active, they all just stopped working (I usually connect out from the server machine, but occasionally I connect in).  Oh, one other clue I can offer -- when I manually killed the sshd daemon I was able to connect one time, then the connections starting failing again.  As soon as I killed the smbd instances, ssh connections starting working again.

Answer (score 0):

First, Mint installs Samba out of the box. You shouldn't need to do anything special to have Samba. Second, all you need to do for SSH is run: `sudo apt-get install ssh` . Third, if you type `sudo service ssh status` you will see the status of your SSH server. If you see something like 'ssh: unrecognized service' then you do not have it installed. If you do have it installed but it is not running then you may want to try running the daemon directly in order to see any errors which may be displayed:

```
$(which sshd) -Ddp 10222
```

The output of this command should give you an idea of what is really happening if the process is killed immediately after starting. If this works, then you should be able to connect on port 10222. This is non default so that you may ensure that the port isn't the problem as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and clarifications.  I updated my question.

Comment: I can tell you that I literally just did this and with a fresh install this is not a problem at all. I'm not sure what you have going on but it is probably something you've changed. Also, if you haven't done so yet, run the deamon on a non default port and connect to it through that port to double check that nothing else is using that port and that there are no error messages.